# Dual monitor fails on Windows 7 using HDMI

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a desktop PC with two different displays, connected through HDMI.

When I start Windows 7 it works fine, displays are recognized and they work. After a while, when the displays are turned off either by power saving or screen lock, the second screen stops to work.

I usually try to disconnect and reconnect the cable (in this way the second display is recognized again by the system), duplicate and then extend again the two displays, but this sometimes works and sometimes not.

The display does not receive signal even if it is recognized by the system.

I tried to update the driver of the video card, but it seems it is up-to-date.

The only solution I found is to reboot the system, but obviously that's not always possible.

Comment: So Windows always recognizes the screens but the secondary screen doesn't receive a signal? My guess would be a faulty HDMI cable.

Comment: Hi @cascer1, the problem is that if I reboot and keep the screen awake, also for a long time, I don't have any problem. The problem arise when my display goes to sleep. For this reason I think that my HDMI cable is fine, also because it is very new and I get the same problem switching the cables between the two screens.

Comment: Hi @cascer1, one update. Sometimes the problem happens with the primary screen, while the secondary works. So my guess is that's not a faulty HDMI cable..

Comment: I'm afraid I have no clue what might be causing it then, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that setting Power Save options, in order to not put the display to sleep, solves the problem.
The option in Windows 7 is on menu:

- Control Panel
- System and Security
- Change when the computer sleeps
- Turn off the display: set to Never